# Dial -Out with Asterisk Sip - circuit is busy error

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip-server

Okey İ handled my problem,

### Problem is provider. it is rejected my request! All problem provider that means trunk!

I have a asterisk server 1.6 and a trunk. i tried to call my cell phone on trunk(provider)
when i call my cell phone it gives me :

```
-- Executing [0506610XXXX@phone:1] NoOp("SIP/1001-0000009b", "") in new stack
-- Executing [0506610XXXX@phone:2] Dial("SIP/1001-0000009b", "SIP/312XXXXXXX
/0506610XXXX") in new stack
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called 312XXXXXXX/0506610XXXX
    -- SIP/3XXXXXXXX-0000009c is circuit-busy
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
    -- Executing [0506610XXXX@phone:3] Hangup("SIP/1001-0000009b", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (phone, 0506610XXXX, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/1001-0000009b'
```

i tried varios things;

#sip show peers- all ok all registered
#sip show registry - my trunk is ok registered

my sip.conf

```
[general] 
register=>XXXXXX:XXXXXX@ipaddress/312911
[312911]
type=friend 
secret=XXXXX 
username=312911
 host=ipaddress
insecure=invite ,port
context=aaa
[1001]
type=friend
dtmfmode=rfc2833
context=phone
host=dynamic
secret=XX
callerID="1001"<1001>
nat=yes
```

my extension.conf

```
[myphones]
exten=> _XXX.,1,NoOp()
exten=> _XXX.,n,Dial(SIP/312911/${EXTEN})

exten=> _XXX.,n,Hangup()

[incoming]
exten=>_X.,1,NoOp()
exten=>_X.,n,Dial(SIP/1001)
exten=> _X.,n,Hangup()

[internal]
exten=>_1XXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten=>_1XXX,n,Hangup()

[phone]
include=>internal
include=>myphones


[aaa]
include=>incoming
include=>myphones
```

Answer (score 1):

Some common causes which will generate this kind of error:
**1)** Provider needs registration where you are not giving register and only created peer.
**2)** The format is wrong. Some provider needs 00 as ISD, some do not. So check that you are using the correct number format.
**3)** The outbound circuit is full. It happens where there is no channel left from the provider side or you are not allowed to create more channels.
 
**4)** Some providers don't support multiple registry.

Fore more details you need to enable "sip set debug ip < provider ip address> and then make the call and check each packet.

Answer (score 0):

on asterisk console: 
set verbose 0 // optional
set debug 0 // optional

set sip debug

it seems that your trunk is not working(wrong number format, invalid login/pass,...)

in sip messages U'll see real error

Comment: Yeah u right  i solved problem , all about provider context. it dont let me call. Anyway thanks for reply